# Strange behaviour in a while loop with a date compare in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, while-loop

Hi I am trying to create a simple while loop that pulls an associative array from a database in PHP. In essence I want to then do a compare on the date pulled from the database with the current date. Here is the catch. Different sections (represented in a table) have different deadlines. So I need to modify the pulled date from the database by subtracting certain amounts of days. I have done this with different variables but I get some weird results which are not the ones I have specified. Am i missing something?

```
$today = date("Y-m-d") 

while ($query_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))

                    {          

    $date =  $query_row['DueDate'];// this is the due date from the  server
    $duedate = $date->format('d-m-Y'); // to output in table
    $compare1 = $date;
    $compare2 = $date;
    $compare3 = $date;
    $compare4 = $date;                             
    $compare1->modify('-4 days');
    $compare2->modify('-3 days');
    $compare3->modify('-2 days');
    $compare4->modify('-1 day');


    echo $today.' today <br/>';
    //just for debugging
    echo $date ->format('Y-m-d').' due date <br/>';
    echo $compare1->format('Y-m-d').' minus 4 date <br/>';

    if (  $today >= $compare1 )
    {   

        $Triginsert = 'style="background-color: #ff0000;"';

    }
    else 
    {

        $Triginsert = '';
    }
    }
```

As you can see if the current date is greater than or equal to the compared date which should be the date pulled from server - 4 days then it should turn the block red else it should do nothing..

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `strtotime()` and make sure the format of both the date are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's happening is that since objects are assigned by reference in php 5+, all your $compare variables are references to the same original $date object. So you are modifying the same one repeatedly instead of creating 4 separate ones. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php .
What you want instead is:

```
$compare1 = clone $date;
$compare2 = clone $date;
etc.
```

BTW what do you get when you var_dump($query_row['DueDate']) ? I was assuming it was already a date object, otherwise the ->modify() calls would error immediately, and you were saying you were getting weird behavior rather than an error message, but some of the other answers are assuming that $query_row['DueDate'] is a string so I wanted to double check.

Comment: Thank you very much that certainly helped get rid of the strange readouts! coming from a C#m background php is all very new to me, similar syntax but those little things like this are what get me.

Comment: You are correct. $query_row['DueDate'] should already be a Date as its coming from SQL as a DATE type. However, I am not sure if PHP can interpret this automatically and assign the $date as a Date object or if its like c# and you have to tell it (that never made sense to me they are both the same company! (c# and MS sql i mean))

Comment: turns out my other error was in my while loop (I was deleting then entire set of variables!) But this has solved the prblem. Many thanks for you help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The data from the query will be just text not a Date object, you need to setup the object using that data to achieve what you want

```
$date = new DateTime($query_row['DueDate']);
```

The problems you are going to have are based on the form of DueDate so you may need to manipulate it first.

Here is an explanation of setting up a Date object http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
$date =  $query_row['DueDate'];// this is the due date from the  server
^^^^^^----string
$duedate = $date->format('d-m-Y'); // to output in table
           ^^^^^---using string as an object
```

You need to pass your `$date` STRING to the DateTime system via a constructor, e.g.

```
$date = new DateTime($query_row['DueDate']);
```

THEN you can start using it as an object.

Comment: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string is the error when I try and pass this argument. Its worth noting that ['DueDate'] is of type Date in the Sql server so I am not sure if PHP assigns the variable as object DateTime or if it takes everything as a string variable??